# Bayes classifier results on a sliding scale

Tags: machine-learning, slider, percentage, bayesian, naivebayes

So, I have a Naive Bayes classifier that predicts the mood of a given phrase or sentence. The actual classification works great but I'm having trouble coming up with a visualization for it.

Simple example of classification:

"Yellow flowers are fantastic"

Mood probabilities:

- 55% Excited
- 5%  Happy
- 5%  Neutral
- 5%  Sad
- 30% Angry

Here, the singular predicted mood is Excited, with a probability of 55%.

My idea for a visualization was to show only the two extremes: Excited and Angry. In this first example, the scale might look something like this: [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5T6Cm.png)

However, let's say the prediction was something like this:

- 1%   Excited
- 1%   Happy
- 1%   Neutral
- 96%  Sad
- 1%   Angry

I would expect the scale to look like so: [Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRktY.png):

How could i get the indicator to essentially the 66% point from this data that I have?

Comment: Your last line "How could i get the indicator to essentially the 66% point from this data that I have?" is unclear. Can you clarify?

Comment: on the scale that I have (see image) if 0% is the far left and 100% is the far right, the tick would be at 66%